# How to compare two tags and generate xml template using xlst

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have xml with tag, updateTypes with possible values "LINE","HEADER". It can be only "LINE" or "HEADER". Or It can be combination of both "LINE" and "HEADER".

**XML with LINE and HEADER**

```
<message>
    <orderOfficeId>1</orderOfficeId>
    <channelMthdCd>1</channelMthdCd>
    <updateTypes>LINE</updateTypes>
    <updateTypes>HEADER</updateTypes>
<message>
```

**XML with LINE**

```
<message>
    <orderOfficeId>1</orderOfficeId>
    <channelMthdCd>1</channelMthdCd>
    <updateTypes>LINE</updateTypes>
<message>
```

**XML with HEADER**

```
<message>
    <orderOfficeId>1</orderOfficeId>
    <channelMthdCd>1</channelMthdCd>
    <updateTypes>HEADER</updateTypes>
<message>
```

Here is my xslt, which needs to generate xml based on updateType value. It was working fine for the one possible case. But its not working for multiple values for that tag.Can I know how can I make sure it should work based on the values effectively, it could be one updateType or combination of both.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<MESSAGE>
    <SEG>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="message/updateTypes= 'HEADER'">
              <HEAD>
                  <TEST>HEAD</TEST>
                  <TYP>C</TYP>
              </HEAD>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="message/updateTypes= 'LINE' and 'HEADER'">
              <HEAD>
                  <TEST>HEAD</TEST>
                  <TYP>D</TYP>
              </HEAD>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="message/updateTypes= 'LINE'">
               <HEAD>
                  <TEST>HEAD</TEST>
                  <TYP>B</TYP>
              </HEAD>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>   

    </SEG>
</MESSAGE>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<message>
      <SEG>
         <HEAD>
              <TEST>HEAD</TEST>
              <TYP>B</TYP>
          </HEAD>
      </SEG>
    <message>
```

**EXPECTED-OUTPUT:**

```
<message>
      <SEG>
         <HEAD>
              <TEST>HEAD</TEST>
              <TYP>D</TYP>
          </HEAD>
      </SEG>
    <message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/message">
    <MESSAGE>
        <SEG>
            <HEAD>
                <TEST>HEAD</TEST>
                <TYP>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="updateTypes='HEADER' and updateTypes='LINE'">D</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="updateTypes='LINE'">B</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="updateTypes='HEADER'">C</xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </TYP>
            </HEAD>
        </SEG>
    </MESSAGE>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the order of tests matters; `xsl:choose` will return the content of the **first** `xsl:when` element whose *test* returns true.